# Performing phone number validation on textfield depending on regular expression in iPhone

Tags: iphone, objective-c

I have a textfield in my application where i am performing validation for phonenumber (+00-0000000000) that user must enter first '+'then the country code which will be more than 2 digits and after the country code '-' and after '-' mobile number will be entered which be any no digits long.

I have done the code using regular expression but when I initially enter any alphabet in the textfield in place of '+' my app crashes and when I enter +00- i.e +countrycode- and then any alphabet say 'abc' it accepts which is wrong. I want that only digits and + and - must be entered in the textfield. If anything other than digits and + and - is entered for eg if an alphabet is entered in the textfield then an alertview should be shown that "Please Enter Valid Mobile Number".

This is my code:

```
- (BOOL)validateInputWithString:(NSString *)aString
{
    NSString * const regularExpression = @"^([+]{1})([0-9]{2,6})([-]{1})([0-9]{10})$";
    NSError *error = NULL;
}



-(IBAction)Check:(id)sender{
    BOOL check = [self validateInputWithString:TextField.text];

    if(check == YES){
        NSLog(@"Hii");
        NSString *string= [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", TextField.text];
        NSArray *first = [string componentsSeparatedByString:@"-"];
        NSString *second = [first objectAtIndex:1];
        NSString *third = [first objectAtIndex:0];
        if([second length] < 11){
            NSLog(@"bang");
        }
        else{
            NSLog(@"Fault");
        }
        if([third length] > 3 || [third length] < 7){ 
            NSLog(@"Bang");
        }
        else{
            NSLog(@"fault");
        }
    }
    else{
        NSLog(@"FAULT");
    }
}
```

But here in my code when I enter alphabets after +countrycode- then it accepts which is wrong and when I enter alphabet initially in my textfile then my app crashes on my button click.

Comment: you are missing a return (at least) in `validateInputWithString:`

Comment: Do you really mean to enforce that the country code has 2 digits? the country code for the US is "1".

Comment: @MichaelSlade ok then country code length should be  minimum 1 and how  to put restrictions to check that no characters are entered in the textfield

Answer (score 1):

your app crashes because of this:

```
NSString *string= [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", TextField.text];
NSArray *first = [string componentsSeparatedByString:@"-"];
NSString *second = [first objectAtIndex:1];
NSString *third = [first objectAtIndex:0];
```

First of all your variable names are not good. Why is first an array, second the second string and third the first string? Makes no sense, and nobody will ever understand this code.

But your crash comes because you separate the string and then without checking if it exists you access the objectAtIndex 1. Which of course does not exist if the string does not contain `-`.

Something like this will fix your problem:

```
NSString *string= [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", TextField.text];
NSArray *components = [string componentsSeparatedByString:@"-"];
NSString *strBeforeDash = [components objectAtIndex:0];
if ([components count] > 2) {
    NSLog(@"More than one \"-\" found");
    return;
}
if ([components count == 1) {
    NSLog(@"No \"-\" found");
    return;
}
NSString *strAfterDash = [components objectAtIndex:1];
```

---

and `- (BOOL)validateInputWithString:(NSString *)aString` does not validate anything because it has neither validation code nor a return value.

Comment: Thanks for the answer but here how to for the user that the first value he has to enter is '+'

Comment: Sorry, I don't know. I'm just here to show you what you did wrong. I can't write the validation for you. Start by fixing those bugs, implement `- (BOOL)validateInputWithString:(NSString *)aString` and start experimenting again.